# Video size optimization

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm working on a task that should optimize the video's size before uploading to the server in a web application.
So i want my model to automatically optimize each input video size.

I have many trials in different approaches like FFmpeg:
I used libx265, h264 and lib265 as a codec, with some videos it increases the video size and others minimize it with little ratio and it takes so long to generate the output file.

for example with video of size 8M

```
input = {input_name: None}
output = {output_name: '-n preset faster -vcodec libx265 -crf 28'}
```

The output file is 10M.

And also tried OpenCV:
But the output videos aren't written the file appears 0kb size.

ex: with input video resolution (1280×544)
I want to down scale it by:

```
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XDIV')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, codec, 28.0 , (640,480))
While cap.isOpened():
   bol, frame = cap.read()
   out.write(frame)
   cv2.imshow('video', frame)
```

I become little bit confused. what are the parameters of the input,output videos i should consider to be optimized and make a vital size change in each specific video? Is it the codec, width, height only?

What is the most effective approach to do this?

Should  i build a predictive model for estimating the suitable output video file parameters or there is a method that auto adjust ?

if there's an illustrative example please provide me.

Comment: I also know about bitrate and crf but i still don't know how to use it to optimize the videos.                        And I read lot of comments here around the problem and i have applied lots of trials but i didn't get the result wanted yet.

Comment: You can resize the frame before saving it to reduce file size. In this case you can downsize using [`imutils.resize()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#resizing) to maintain aspect ratio

Comment: Assuming you've omitted the code where the `VideoCapture video` is initialized and the while loop runs at least once, the program should output some sort of error message. Can you include it? Also by optimizing size do you mean bitrate, filesize or resolution?

Comment: @zteffi, I have edited the code above that's what i'm already using it was  have some typos in the post, and i mean by optimization the most efficient way to reduce the video file size regardless it's by minimizing bitrate or resolution. What do you recommend me most ? The files durations will be around 15 ~ 25 sec not very big but i want a better difference between the original and produced videos.

Comment: I'd recommend resizing resolution only if the video will be viewed in smaller resolution. You can resize videos through ffmpeg, so you don't  need OpenCV at all. I'd just use slower preset (you're using *faster* for some reason) and perhaps increase CRF parameter as well. For your problem, you don't need to limit bitrate directly since you don't seem to need to hit certain filesize or bitrate, you're just trying to compress the videos.

Comment: [Here's](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) encoding guide explaining the parameters for h.264.  All the parameters apply for H.265 as well.

Comment: If the input is already "optimized" (compressed efficiently using modern encoder), then it will be challenging to decrease the file size and not reduce quality too much. Also, it is not a fair comparison as your re-encoded outputs now have to deal with the compression artifacts of generation loss which may damage compressibility.